# CNN - Convolutional Filter and MaxPooling

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wrote a code which takes a **6x6 2d array**, multiplies it with a Convolutional Filter and Max Pools it without an activation function or bias and without backpropagation.

The 6x6 2D array is just an array of 0's and 1's which looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0 ,0 , 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

When I maxpool this to a 1D array of size 4 (Reshaped from 2x2 to 4), everytime I run the code I get different values, shouldn't I be getting the same values for the same 6x6 array?

Here is an example:

- **First run:**

`[0.33306642 0.09141601 0.26856917 0.37411067]`

- **Second Run:**

`[0.38857161 0.21194122 0.17829732 0.49700163]`

- **Third Run:**

`[0.14906256 0.1589051  0.23767894 0.35767743]`

Is there something wrong or is it normal to get different values each time even **tho the 6x6 array isn't changing**?

Comment: It would be helpful to add the code so we can replicate the error.

Comment: I solved it, added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it should've had the same values.
I was not doing backpropagation so I was not updating the convolutional filter, it was getting random values each time.

So I solved it by hardcoding the convolutional filter.